# Building universal binaries on Mac - Forcing single compiler child process

Tags: python, macos, gcc, multicore

Cheers,

at company, we're creating a port of our games, and we need to compile [PythonOgre](http://www.pythonogre.com/), a wrapper of Ogre3d for Python. This is an enormous chunk of code, particularly the generated wrapper code. We have a Mac Mini with 1GB RAM.

We've built i386 version. Since we have only 1GB of RAM, we've forced the build system to use only one core; second process running at the same time took a nice trip into the virtual memory.

Now, we need to produce universal binaries, because publisher insists on supporting PPC. To facilitate building of universal binaries, we've modified the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` to include `-arch i386 -arch ppc` when compiling wrapper code (Ogre3d itself already seems to be an universal binary).

However, Apple has decided to use both cores when creating universal binary, and this has caused the system to roll over and die. (Well, crawl at 0.9-1.4% CPU usage, anyways.) While ordinarily we would appreciate this, on a 1GB Mac Mini, this completely blocks our development.

Aside from getting a new build machine, giving up on PPC support and producing a PPC-only build, the only recourse we have is to block GCC's spawning of second simultaneous process.

How would we go about that?

Comment: Surely it would be cheaper to get a better build machine or at least to increase its memory

Comment: @Mark, absolutely: 4-GB kits of RAM for Intel Mac Minis cost around $90 from reputable 3rd party suppliers (in the US, but I don't think they'll cost _that_ much more in Croatia) -- definitely the best approach here, IMHO.

Comment: I am not sure what you guys mean by "cheaper" -- this is a one time build and usually we won't exactly build such large wrappers :-) Nevertheless, this was the first thing I suggested not because it's cheap, but because it's quick to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the source of Apple's GCC driver (the one that supports those `-arch` options and runs the children processes), and there's no option or environment variable that you can choose.

The only options I see left to you are:

- download the Apple driver (e.g. from [there](http://r.research.att.com/tools/); end of the page) and modify the file `driverdriver.c` so that processes are launched sequentially (rather than in parallel)
- do separate i386 and powerpc builds, and join the final build objects (executables, shared libraries, etc.) using `lipo`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I've taken a look at the driver code (darwin-driver.c) but since I cannot quickly find the call to fork() we won't be going that way. On the other hand, yesterday we quickly created the ppc build and lipo seems rather simple to use so we'll merge i386 and ppc .so's with lipo. Thank you!

Comment: The driver doesn't call fork() directly, it calls a function named pexecute(), which hides system-specific behaviour (GCC works on non-POSIX platforms such as Windows! the library providing this is libiberty, which is included in GCC).

Answer (score 1):

Will just turning off one core do? Apparently, installing the Apple Developer Tools (XCode et al.) gives you a Processor system preference pane, allowing you to turn off one core. I was trying to test this, but the XCode install failed for some reason...

EDIT: I know this was a while ago, but I just thought of something. Why not build with -march=i386 and -march=ppc separately and then combine the binaries using lipo?

Comment: I've just got it installed and it works as advertised. If the prefPane fails to install after installing the developer tools, you can find it at /Developer/Extras/PreferencePanes/ , provided you installed the dev tools at the default location.

Comment: We're currently building PPC-only version (deadlines, oh deadlines), so I can't test. But I suspect this does the same thing as /Library/Application Support/HW Prefs/CPU Palette which did NOT help, since GCC didn't act upon the fact that there's only one core active and it happily spawned the second process.